# Buffer Overflow with size_t in C

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

why does the following code can lead to a buffer overflow? I know the problem is with the `size_t`. But I don't know why. Could someone explain it to me?

```
#include <stddef.h>
#define COLS 5
#define ROWS 7
static int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
 
void init_matrix(int x) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
      matrix[i][j] = x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be matrix[j][i] = x; you've got COLS and ROWS the wrong way around.

Comment: @RichardBamford (exclusive) or `i < ROWS` and `j < COLS`

Answer (score 2):

Just Swap i and j in the loop or change i and j in `matrix[j][i]` it should work fine.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
        matrix[j][i] = x;
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

In your code, you have used the for loop in the wrong way. The outer loop is the `i`th one and inner loop is the `j`th one.

The inner loop will complete it's iteration for every valid value of `i`.

In your code. You have constrained `j < ROWS`, So it means you should use `j` for rows. but while assigning value, you have used the `j` variable for columns. According to your code `j` can be equal to 5. But it will throw an error at run time that array index out of bound or similar error as you are using variable `j` for columns. and the maximum index the column can have is 4.

So either you should do `i < ROWS` and `j < COLS` or you should change the variables while assigning the value `matrix[j][i] = x;` as I did above.

Answer (score 0):

The array `matrix` has only `COLS` (5) columns, but the loop to access the columns goes upto `ROWS-1` (6). Overflow here.

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) J.2 Undefined behavior says:

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the
> given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int
> a[4][5]) (6.5.6).